# Select pairs from an array (matching game) And add sound to that selection AS3 Flash CS4

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, cs4

I'm using a tutorial I found on Google - which works well. However, I have a few issues to make it work how I would like.     This code uses a MovieClip for the card faces with the back of the card on frame1 and 2-17 different pictures or movieclips.

The questions are - Is there a way to get the ActionScript to choose from the whole array? But still produce pairs to choose from. As it stands now - If  I select the game to be 4 across by 2 down (8 cards in total) It has the back of card (frame1) and will then randomly select, but only from frames 2-5 .  If I modify these lines...

```
    public function MatchingGameObject10():void {
        // make a list of card numbers
        var cardlist:Array = new Array();
        for(var i:uint=0;i<boardWidth*boardHeight/2;i++) {
            cardlist.push(i);
            cardlist.push(i);
    }
```

to

```
    public function MatchingGameObject10():void {
        // make a list of card numbers
        var cardlist:Array = new Array(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17);
    }
```

I get random cards - but no pairs...

If I can ask another question here - it is - how to add a seperate sound to each card..So if it shows a Bee - the Bee.mp3 is played..   Here's the whole code..

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

public class MatchingGameObject10 extends MovieClip {
    // game constants
    private static const boardWidth:uint = 4;
    private static const boardHeight:uint = 2;
    private static const cardHorizontalSpacing:Number = 500;
    private static const cardVerticalSpacing:Number = 700;
    private static const boardOffsetX:Number = 50;
    private static const boardOffsetY:Number = 70;
    private static const pointsForMatch:int = 10;
    private static const pointsForMiss:int = -1;

    // variables
    private var firstCard:Card10;
    private var secondCard:Card10;
    private var cardsLeft:uint;
    private var gameScore:int;
    private var gameStartTime:uint;
    private var gameTime:uint;

    // text fields
    private var gameScoreField:TextField;
    private var gameTimeField:TextField;

    // timer to return cards to face-down
    private var flipBackTimer:Timer;

    // set up sounds
    var theFirstCardSound:FirstCardSound = new FirstCardSound();
    var theMissSound:MissSound = new MissSound();
    var theMatchSound:MatchSound = new MatchSound();

    // initialization function
    public function MatchingGameObject10():void {
        // make a list of card numbers
        var cardlist:Array = new Array();
        for(var i:uint=0;i<boardWidth*boardHeight/2;i++) {
            cardlist.push(i);
            cardlist.push(i);
        }

        // create all the cards, position them, and assign a randomcard face to each
        cardsLeft = 0;
        for (var x:uint=0; x<boardWidth; x++) {// horizontal
            for (var y:uint=0; y<boardHeight; y++) {// vertical
                var c:Card10 = new Card10();// copy the movie clip
                c.stop();// stop on first frame
                c.x = x*cardHorizontalSpacing+boardOffsetX;// set position
                c.y = y*cardVerticalSpacing+boardOffsetY;
                var r:uint = Math.floor(Math.random()*cardlist.length);// get a random face
                c.cardface = cardlist[r];// assign face to card
                cardlist.splice(r,1);// remove face from list
                c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickCard);// have it listen for clicks
                c.buttonMode = true;
                addChild(c);// show the card
                cardsLeft++;
            }
        }

        // set up the score
        gameScoreField = new TextField();
        addChild(gameScoreField);
        gameScore = 0;
        showGameScore();

        // set up the clock
        gameTimeField = new TextField();
        gameTimeField.x = 450;
        addChild(gameTimeField);
        gameStartTime = getTimer();
        gameTime = 0;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,showTime);
    }

    // player clicked on a card
    public function clickCard(event:MouseEvent) {
        var thisCard:Card10 = (event.target as Card10); // what card?

        if (firstCard == null) { // first card in a pair
            firstCard = thisCard; // note it
            thisCard.startFlip(thisCard.cardface+2);
            playSound(theFirstCardSound);

        } else if (firstCard == thisCard) { // clicked first card again
            firstCard.startFlip(1);
            firstCard = null;
            playSound(theMissSound);

        } else if (secondCard == null) { // second card in a pair
            secondCard = thisCard; // note it
            thisCard.startFlip(thisCard.cardface+2);

            // compare two cards
            if (firstCard.cardface == secondCard.cardface) {
                // remove a match
                removeChild(firstCard);
                removeChild(secondCard);
                // reset selection
                firstCard = null;
                secondCard = null;
                // add points
                gameScore += pointsForMatch;
                showGameScore();
                playSound(theMatchSound);
                // check for game over
                cardsLeft -= 2; // 2 less cards
                if (cardsLeft == 0) {
                    MovieClip(root).gameScore = gameScore;
                    MovieClip(root).gameTime = clockTime(gameTime);
                    MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop("gameover");
                }
            } else {
                gameScore += pointsForMiss;
                showGameScore();
                playSound(theMissSound);
                flipBackTimer = new Timer(2000,1);
                flipBackTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,returnCards);
                flipBackTimer.start();
            }

        } else { // starting to pick another pair
            returnCards(null);
            playSound(theFirstCardSound);
            // select first card in next pair
            firstCard = thisCard;
            firstCard.startFlip(thisCard.cardface+2);
        }
    }

    // return cards to face-down
    public function returnCards(event:TimerEvent) {
        firstCard.startFlip(1);
        secondCard.startFlip(1);
        firstCard = null;
        secondCard = null;
        flipBackTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,returnCards);
    }

    public function showGameScore() {
        gameScoreField.text = "Score: "+String(gameScore);
    }

    public function showTime(event:Event) {
        gameTime = getTimer()-gameStartTime;
        gameTimeField.text = "Time: "+clockTime(gameTime);
    }

    public function clockTime(ms:int) {
        var seconds:int = Math.floor(ms/1000);
        var minutes:int = Math.floor(seconds/60);
        seconds -= minutes*60;
        var timeString:String = minutes+":"+String(seconds+100).substr(1,2);
        return timeString;
    }

    public function playSound(soundObject:Object) {
        var channel:SoundChannel = soundObject.play();
    }
}
}
```

Here's Card10 class

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public dynamic class Card extends MovieClip {
    private var flipStep:uint;
    private var isFlipping:Boolean = false;
    private var flipToFrame:uint;

    // begin the flip, remember which frame to jump to
    public function startFlip(flipToWhichFrame:uint) {
        isFlipping = true;
        flipStep = 10;
        flipToFrame = flipToWhichFrame;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, flip);
    }

    // take 10 steps to flip
    public function flip(event:Event) {
        flipStep--; // next step

        if (flipStep > 5) { // first half of flip
            this.scaleX = .20*(flipStep-6);
        } else { // second half of flip
            this.scaleX = .20*(5-flipStep);
        }

        // when it is the middle of the flip, go to new frame
        if (flipStep == 5) {
            gotoAndStop(flipToFrame);
        }

        // at the end of the flip, stop the animation
        if (flipStep == 0) {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, flip);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Looking at the code, I don't see how changing the value of `boardWidth` & `boardHeight` wouldn't accomplish what you want?  As far the sound part goes, you'd need to associate the appropriate sound file with each cardface. It would be helpful if you shared the `Card10` class.

Comment: What it seems to be doing is creating a 'cardlist' based on the board width and length (x2) - But is relating this to equivelent frames. i.e. In my case I have 4x2 - so it only chooses the first 5 frames to pick from.. (frame 1 being the back of the card) . If I change the code to produce a 6x6 board it does include all the frames. So the random function is working - but it is choosing from an array of only the first 4 frames.. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The Card10 class is producing an animation for the flip.. I will edit original post to include this script.

Comment: I've tried to place sound directly on the individual frame - but it diesn't work. If I nest sound on the first level of a Mclip (eg the word 'bee' on the bee' Mclip - it plays that sound for all cards - if I nest the sound in a level deeper on the individual movieclip. That's sound on the timeline, rather than using AS3 to play the osund (which I'm struggling to get my head around.. The joys of being a noob!)

Comment: Can you share the .fla (put it on dropbox or onedrive etc), I think that would be easiest for understanding what's going on?

Comment: Hey. I've uploaded FLA to Dropbox - How do I get you to it?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1xkwrr0o4v4lrsn/AADAF_tSEkRTmxkoPPypodo8a?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So without completely re-factoring how this game works, the best way to make it dynamic based off the amount of frames (card faces) in your `Card10` Clip, is change this code:

```
    var cardlist:Array = new Array();
    for(var i:uint=0;i<boardWidth*boardHeight/2;i++) {
        cardlist.push(i);
        cardlist.push(i);
    }
```

To the following:

```
        var allCards:Array = new Array(); //an array of all available frame numbers
        var cardlist:Array = new Array(); //an array of just those cards to show

        var tmpCard:Card10 = new Card10(); //create a temporary card for the sole purpose of counting how many frames it has

        var i:int;
        //populate the array with all the frames from the Card MC 
        for (i = 0; i < tmpCard.totalFrames;i++) {
            allCards.push(i);//add card frame to allCards array
        }

        //now create the list of cards to show (since the amount of cards may be more than the amount you want to show
        for (i = 0; i < (boardWidth * boardHeight) / 2; i++) {
            var cardIndex:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * allCards.length);// get a random card from the all card list

            //add the card twice (so there is a pair) in the list of cards to show
            cardlist.push(cardIndex);
            cardlist.push(cardIndex);

            //remove it from the all cards array so it doesn't come up again in the random bit above
            allCards.splice(cardIndex,1);
        }
```

Comment: Just a quick issue I noticed - when you select the second card now (as a pair) you don't see it - it just goes to blank..or 'match'. Can I get that to hang on for a short time, so the kid(player)can see the match?

Comment: Nothing has changed in that regard.   Ideally, if it's a match you would want to lock the ability to click other cards while a match animation plays, then once the animation is done run the code in this if statement: `if(firstCard.cardface == secondCard.cardface)`  -  if you're not going to have an animation, you would need to use a timer or setTimeout to delay the code in that if statement for the desired amount of time